# Split file based on beginning and end XML tag

Tags: text-processing, xml, split, macos

Can split be used to split a file into multiple segments where the size of each segment is based on the number of matches of an XML element ?

For example for below XML split when encounters of `"<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">`" is 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
</testers>
```

Splitting the above XML file should generate 2 files.

file1 :

```
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
```

and file 2 containing just a single entry :

```
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
```

Here is what I'm trying :

```
split -p "<test xsi:type=\"update\" locale=\"en_US\">" test.xml segment
```

which outputs 4 files:

segmentaa :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

segmentab :

```
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
```

segmentac :

```
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
```

segmentad :

```
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
</testers>
```

Can `split` be utilised in the way I'm suggesting. The file I'm processing is 40GB, I use the above example to illustrate the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its possible with `split`. You could use `awk`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ 
    fmt="segment%02d"               # 2 digits for suffix, zero padded
    start="<test xsi:type=\"update\" locale=\"en_US\">"
    end="</test>"
  }
  $0 == start, $0 == end{
    if ($0 == start && ++cnt%2==1){ # for every 2nd start element...
      fname=sprintf(fmt, fcnt++)    # update output filename
    }
    print $0 > fname                # print line, redirect output to fname
  }
' test.xml
```

This produces two files `segment00` and `segment01`:

```
$ head segment*
==> segment00 <==
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>

==> segment01 <==
<test xsi:type="update" locale="en_US">
<rval>1</rval>
</test>
```